logroate's postrotate not being executed
I have following logrotate configurations:
/var/log/elastic/*.log {
  su root root
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 60
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  create 640 elastic elastic
  postrotate
    mv -f /var/log/elastic/*.gz /backup/elastic/logs/
  endscript
}

It runs daily and makes .gz archives. However, I want those archives to be moved to the specified location in postrotate, which never happens. Running the config with -d also doesnt show postrotate script being executed.
Am I missing something with the configs?
